# Understanding Dynamic Programming through this example

Tags: dynamic-programming, recursion

I have trouble understanding The classic Mailbox Manufacturers Problem. You can read it here: https://open.kattis.com/problems/mailbox I have also found a solution text: http://www.ida.liu.se/projects/progcontest/progsm/2002/prognm2002-hints.pdf

I just cant get my head around this problem and i cant even understand the solution given above. For example what does "minimum number of fire-crackers that is needed, in the worst case" mean? What is the worst case? If i have 2 boxes each fitting 4 crackers, how can the answer be 7?

I have also looked at codes that solved this problems but couldt understand the solution either and yes i am familiar with recursion and some DP but still cant get this one. Anyone care to explaing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make you question self-contained? Links tend to rot.

Comment: The worst case is the case where you didn't make any lucky guesses, for example by starting with just the right number of crackers.